# Is there a way to specify a name for foreign constraints in the schema builder of Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Why the foreign constraint name have no the prefix specified by `'DB_PREFIX'`? Two programs using the same database would fail, because they have the same constraint name . I try to google it and read in Laravel documentation but I can't get anything about it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to the [API docs](http://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Database/Schema/Blueprint.html#method_foreign) you can give the contraint a custom name

```
Fluent foreign(string|array $columns, string $name = null)
```

Comment: conforming convention may be better.   : ).  let me try to issue to official